# Is it Possible to call Functions and Stored Procedures of One database In another database- Azure Sql server

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to call function from another database to a database within the Azure sql. That is , 
there is a function in DB1. I need that same function in DB2.
How to call it from DB2? 
Both database are in azure Sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can see this documentation:[Reporting across scaled-out cloud databases (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-horizontal-partitioning).

Elastic query also introduces a stored procedure that provides direct access to the shards. The stored procedure is called sp_execute _remote and can be used to execute remote stored procedures or T-SQL code on the remote databases. It takes the following parameters:

1. Data source name (nvarchar): The name of the external data source of type RDBMS.
2. Query (nvarchar): The T-SQL query to be executed on each shard.
3. Parameter declaration (nvarchar) - optional: String with data type definitions for the 4. parameters used in the Query parameter (like sp_executesql).
4. Parameter value list - optional: Comma-separated list of parameter values (like sp_executesql).

The sp_execute_remote uses the external data source provided in the invocation parameters to execute the given T-SQL statement on the remote databases. It uses the credential of the external data source to connect to the shardmap manager database and the remote databases.

Example:

```
 EXEC sp_execute_remote
        N'MyExtSrc',
        N'select count(w_id) as foo from warehouse'
```

It means that you can call the  Functions and Stored Procedures of One database In another database, just need to modify the SQL statement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, It's working!!.  One more doubt is there any possibility to access that function like functions in the same Database?. (eg.  'Select  OtherDatabaseFunctionName(parameter) as ColumnName')

Comment: Hi @SumithJose, I'm not sure if it's possible, and I haven't find examples about that. If my answer helps you, could you please accept it? Thanks and have a good day.